Cannot resolve symbol "package list" in Inteillij
I'm just build a common package (), which is will be import my main project and used in my all spring boot project. I already added it in my pom.xml
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.minastik</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

When I try extends one of class of common package , such as BaseRedisConfig like this:

Intellij still recognize my common package. But when i press tab button, an error occurred:

In tab Maven :

Intellij still use Redis package in my common but doesn't recognize my common package ??
I tried Invalidate Caches and Restart but it not worked for me
Does anyone have an idea for this ? Sorry my english isn't good. Thanks a lot

Have you tried reloading maven project, so that it sees the added dependency? (right click on pom.xml -> under Maven -> Reload Project)

@asgarov1 yeah i tried but it still not working
